# How can I change the color of tentative ("Maybe") events in Calendar?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, calendar

I'd like to differentiate more between "Accepted" and "Maybe" events on my Calendar app.  Right now "Maybe" events are pinstriped with the same color scheme as "Accepted" events, and it's hard to differentiate them at a glance.  I'd rather they be different colors, though the pinstripes can remain.

How can I do this?

I'm on High Sierra, version 10.13.6.

Comment: Can we assume you're talking about the default Calendar app in macOS?

Comment: Yes, the Calendar app.

Answer (score 1):

I have a calendar for tentative events and I move them there / make that my default calendar.

Once I accept the meeting, I recategorize it according to my other colors / must attend / optional / travel / etc...

It’s not automatic, but it works to get things color coded.

Comment: Unfortunately this is my Outlook work calendar and it all has to stay on the same calendar...  That would be a good idea for a personal calendar!

Comment: Oh outlook - no you have to tag things there as well but you might be able to build a flow at portal.office.com depending on your license and desire to automate this. I've only seen that if you use outlook though for hosting the O365 calendar - not using Apple calendar to pull the data down @AmandaS